# Excel 2010 VBA Update Connection script stopped working

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I wrote a VBA script to update the connections on all pivot tables to a new existing connection in my workbook. This worked fine but I tried using the script again and I got a object-defined or application-defined error.

Script

```
Private Function changeDataSource()
Dim wrkbk As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim pTable As pivotTable

Set wrkbk = Workbooks(workBookName)

For Each sheet In wrkbk.Worksheets
    Debug.Print "Sheet Name: " & sheet.Name
    For Each pTable In sheet.PivotTables
        Debug.Print "Pivot table: " & pTable.Name
        pTable.ChangeConnection wrkbk.Connections("ConnectionName")
    Next pTable
    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------"
Next sheet
End Function
```

PS. The connection is to another excel file which was made using MS query.

Also note this is on excel 2010 using windows 7.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Where have you defined/declared `workBookName`? Check if `wrkbk is nothing` before proceeding with the `for-each` loop.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules to prevent some of these issues